# Why does PrefixUnaryExpressionSyntax of Kind PreIncrement allow for Operands of ParanthesisedExpressionsSyntax's?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to understand how the C# analyzers and compilers work.

Unary operators like pre-inc and post-inc should only accept variables, properties and indexers, according to docs.

Interestingly they also accept ParanthesisedExpressions, such as the code ++(x);

Is there a syntactic reason for this? Are there any other circumstances where ++(..something here..) works other than that the ParanthesizedExpressionSyntax is semantically equivalent to the property/indexer/variable?

Comment: What do you mean by a "syntactic reason"?

Comment: @Sweeper Well I mean is there any other supported syntax that could allow an operand of parenthesizedexpression ? Apart from that scenario above where the brackets are analyzed as being redundant and the ParenthesizedExpression is semantically equivalent to the child expression (variable/indexer/property)  .  Off the top of my head, some kind of switch over variable references or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the C# language specifications allow it. The specification of the [preincrement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#prefix-increment-and-decrement-operators) is:

```
pre_increment_expression
    : '++' unary_expression
    ;
```

and the specification for the [unary_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#unary-operators) is:

```
unary_expression
    : primary_expression
    | null_conditional_expression
    | '+' unary_expression
    | '-' unary_expression
    | '!' unary_expression
    | '~' unary_expression
    | pre_increment_expression
    | pre_decrement_expression
    | cast_expression
    | await_expression
    | unary_expression_unsafe
    ;
```

and finally, [primary_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#primary-expressions) allows for parenthesis:

```
primary_expression
    : primary_no_array_creation_expression
    | array_creation_expression
    ;

primary_no_array_creation_expression
    : literal
    | interpolated_string_expression
    | simple_name
    | parenthesized_expression <<---  parenthesized expression
    | member_access
    | invocation_expression
    | element_access
    | this_access
    | base_access
    | post_increment_expression
    | post_decrement_expression
    | object_creation_expression
    | delegate_creation_expression
    | anonymous_object_creation_expression
    | typeof_expression
    | checked_expression
    | unchecked_expression
    | default_value_expression
    | nameof_expression
    | anonymous_method_expression
    | primary_no_array_creation_expression_unsafe
    ;
```

So now the question is: why should `pre_increment_expression` allow a `unary_expression`? Because the alternative would be harder to specify, to develop and then to test. The alternative would have been to write something like this:

```
pre_increment_expression
    : '++' pre_increment_expression_allowed
    ;

pre_increment_expression_allowed
    : element_access
    | member_access
    | some other expressions 
    ;
```

If you don't reuse an existing expression, you'll have to think about all the expressions you want to allow, which can become very complex, and then develop the new syntax tree parsing to support that expression.

**Convoluted example:**

Note that it's possible to write the following (not that it makes much sense, but still):

```cs
void Main()
{
    ++(new MyClass().Prop);
    
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Prop {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It's almost as though the compiler is expecting or trying to *resolve* the operand to a valid symbol first. If I was to write my own compiler using the Roslyn stuff, I wonder how I would go about implementing how the expression is processed....

Comment: Actually, I see. The SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(operand).Symbol works in this case